# Properties which ${\rm GL}_2(q)$ possess but ${\rm GL}_n(q)$ do not for $n>2$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

In *every* text/reference book on group theory, the commonly introduced family of finite simple groups is $A_n$, and then, *some* books give a flavor of ${\rm GL}_n(q)$ with conclusion of simplicity of ${\rm PSL}_n(q)$.

However, some books introduce ${\rm GL}_n(q)$ only in lower dimension- namely $n=2$. Then I wonder about the following question:

**Question:** Does the group ${\rm GL}_2(q)$ possesses some interesting properties which ${\rm GL}_n(q)$ do not possess for $n>2$?

Comment: One guess - $2\times 2$ matrices are not small enough to be boring and not big enough to be annoying.

Comment: It is, for example, "manageable" to produce the complex representation theory of $GL_2(\Bbb{F}_q)$ by inducting from obvious subgroups. I have not seen this done for higher $n$, but that may be mostly because I haven't looked hard enough. OTOH in the algebraic group/Lie group side the representation theory, in some simplified sense, is all about how the various copies of $SL_2$ sitting inside $GL_n$ will interact. This does not really answer your question, but a theme is that understanding the $n=2$ case serves as a building block.

Comment: @Jyrki: your comments are important and give motivation towards representations of $GL_n$ via $GL_2$ or $SL_2$.

Comment: I would say on balance that the answer is no, apart from the fact that ${\rm GL}_2(q)$ is soluble for small $q$ ($q=2,3$). On the other hand, ${\rm PSL}_2({\mathbb Z})$ is different in a lot of respects from  ${\rm PSL}_n({\mathbb Z})$ for $n > 2$.